# How to print class member's data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have

```
class CanIdPropType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arbitration_id = None
        self.dlc = 0
        self.data = {}
        self.timestamp = ""

def Receive():
  CanMessage = CanIdPropType()
  print('CanMessage',CanMessage)
```

In the code above I am trying to print 'CanMessage' but it is printing the address of the class. I want to print the class members values without using bellow format:
`CanMessage.dlc, CanMessage.data`

Comment: Did you only need two attributes? Or all the attributes? @TejeshReddy

Comment: In Python we say "attributes" not "member data", and in this case those are actually instance attributes, not class attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default way of an object is represented by overriding the `__repr__` method.

For example:

```
class CanIdPropType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arbitration_id = None
        self.dlc = 0
        self.data = {}
        self.timestamp = ""

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<CanIdPropType: {self.arbitration_id}, {self.dlc}>"
```

Comment: I just wrote two of the attributes here, but it can obviously be completed with the attributes needed, or even replaced by the `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the dunder method [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) to get the format you need.

You can iterate over the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) which is a dictionary that stores the attributes of the class to get the list of attributes you want

```
class CanIdPropType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arbitration_id = None
        self.dlc = 0
        self.data = {}
        self.timestamp = ""

    def __str__(self):

        #Iterate over all attributes, and create the representative string
        return ', '.join([f'{self.__class__.__name__}:{attr}' for attr in self.__dict__])

CanMessage = CanIdPropType()
print(CanMessage)
```

The output will be

```
CanIdPropType:arbitration_id, CanIdPropType:dlc, CanIdPropType:data, CanIdPropType:timestamp
```

Comment: I generally don't like the use of `__dict__`, because it could print a bunch of private attributes without printing properties that could be needed. Plus you could eventually need to represent some of the attributes either (with a `join`, for example)

Comment: Sure, you can always filter private variables out by checking if they start with an `_` @olinox14 will that improve the usage?

Comment: Of course. Let's say I like to keep control on the way my classes are represented, but that's only my way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.__dict__`:

For normal objects, the `__dict__` object creates a separate dict object, which stores the attributes, and `__getattribute__` first tries to access it and get the attributes from there (before attempting to look for the attribute in the class by utilizing the descriptor protocol, and before calling `__getattr__`). The `__dict__` descriptor on the class implements the access to this dictionary.

```
class CanIdPropType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arbitration_id = None
        self.dlc = 0
        self.data = {}
        self.timestamp = ""

def Receive():
  CanMessage = CanIdPropType()
  print('CanMessage',CanMessage.__dict__)

Receive()
```

output:

```
CanMessage {'arbitration_id': None, 'dlc': 0, 'data': {}, 'timestamp': ''}
```